# In Bootstrap modal i want to add a content slider

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

i tried with some sliders and most of them are not working properly. ijuts want to slide the content with two buttons like "next" "previous" .not automaticaly slide the content , and it should be responsive[image]

Comment: Did you try [Bootstrap 'carousel'](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) ?

Comment: yes i found a modal with the carousel but its not working properly,   i just want a simple content slider .